# datatables dynamic totals in footer on rows change

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have simple datatable with summary of last column (total) in footer:

html:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4" style="text-align:right">Total:</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger</td>
            <td>Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett</td>
            <td>Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton</td>
            <td>Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cedric</td>
            <td>Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Airi</td>
            <td>Satou</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Brielle</td>
            <td>Williamson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>$372,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Herrod</td>
            <td>Chandler</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>$137,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Rhona</td>
            <td>Davidson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>$327,900</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Colleen</td>
            <td>Hurst</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>$205,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sonya</td>
            <td>Frost</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>$103,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jena</td>
            <td>Gaines</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>$90,560</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Quinn</td>
            <td>Flynn</td>
            <td>Support Lead</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>$342,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Charde</td>
            <td>Marshall</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>$470,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Haley</td>
            <td>Kennedy</td>
            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>$313,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tatyana</td>
            <td>Fitzpatrick</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>$385,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michael</td>
            <td>Silva</td>
            <td>Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>$198,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Paul</td>
            <td>Byrd</td>
            <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>$725,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gloria</td>
            <td>Little</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>$237,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bradley</td>
            <td>Greer</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>$132,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Dai</td>
            <td>Rios</td>
            <td>Personnel Lead</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>$217,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jenette</td>
            <td>Caldwell</td>
            <td>Development Lead</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>$345,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Yuri</td>
            <td>Berry</td>
            <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>$675,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Caesar</td>
            <td>Vance</td>
            <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>$106,450</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Doris</td>
            <td>Wilder</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>Sidney</td>
            <td>$85,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Angelica</td>
            <td>Ramos</td>
            <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>$1,200,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gavin</td>
            <td>Joyce</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>$92,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jennifer</td>
            <td>Chang</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>$357,650</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Brenden</td>
            <td>Wagner</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>$206,850</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Fiona</td>
            <td>Green</td>
            <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>$850,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shou</td>
            <td>Itou</td>
            <td>Regional Marketing</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>$163,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michelle</td>
            <td>House</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Sidney</td>
            <td>$95,400</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Suki</td>
            <td>Burks</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>$114,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Prescott</td>
            <td>Bartlett</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>$145,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gavin</td>
            <td>Cortez</td>
            <td>Team Leader</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>$235,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Martena</td>
            <td>Mccray</td>
            <td>Post-Sales support</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>$324,050</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Unity</td>
            <td>Butler</td>
            <td>Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>$85,675</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Howard</td>
            <td>Hatfield</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>$164,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hope</td>
            <td>Fuentes</td>
            <td>Secretary</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>$109,850</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Vivian</td>
            <td>Harrell</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>$452,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Timothy</td>
            <td>Mooney</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>$136,200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>Bradshaw</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>$645,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Olivia</td>
            <td>Liang</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>$234,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bruno</td>
            <td>Nash</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>$163,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sakura</td>
            <td>Yamamoto</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>$139,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Thor</td>
            <td>Walton</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>$98,540</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Finn</td>
            <td>Camacho</td>
            <td>Support Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>$87,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Serge</td>
            <td>Baldwin</td>
            <td>Data Coordinator</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>$138,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Zenaida</td>
            <td>Frank</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>$125,250</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Zorita</td>
            <td>Serrano</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>$115,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jennifer</td>
            <td>Acosta</td>
            <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>$75,650</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cara</td>
            <td>Stevens</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>$145,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hermione</td>
            <td>Butler</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>$356,250</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lael</td>
            <td>Greer</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>$103,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jonas</td>
            <td>Alexander</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>$86,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shad</td>
            <td>Decker</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>$183,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michael</td>
            <td>Bruce</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>$183,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Donna</td>
            <td>Snider</td>
            <td>Customer Support</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>$112,000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
        var api = this.api(), data;

        // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
        var intVal = function ( i ) {
            return typeof i === 'string' ?
                i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                typeof i === 'number' ?
                    i : 0;
        };

        // Total over all pages
        total = api
            .column( 4 )
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0 );

        // Update footer
        $( api.column( 4 ).footer() ).html(
            '$'+ total +' total'
        );
    }
} );
} );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sLxbznx6/

and I want to update total on search keyup.

Can anybody give me any hint to do this? :)

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`selector-modifier`](https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier) `{ search: 'applied' }` as second argument for [`column()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column()) API method.

Change:

```
total = api
   .column(4)
   .data()
   .reduce( function (a, b) {
      return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
   }, 0 );
```

to

```
total = api
   .column( 4, { search: 'applied' } )
   .data()
   .reduce( function (a, b) {
      return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
   }, 0 );
```

See [updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLxbznx6/1/) for code and demonstration.